# If not exists then insert to c# Windows form data inserting

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

I've created data updating form using C# winform. i need to add if the data not exists insert data. if exist check from database display message data already inserted.
here is my code and winfirm image.

please help me to do this.

i tried using IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM WHERE) but it;s not working properly

when i Add if Exists code

```html
string sql =  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM   UserInfo WHERE  User_Name = @Name) 
                    BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO UserInfo (User_Name, Email,EPF_Number, Department, Laptop_Model, Laptop_Serial,  Issu_Date,Hostname, Image) VALUES  ( @Name,@Email, @EPFNumber, @DPT, @Model,@Serial,@Date, @Host, @Photo)
                    END
```

It shows below errors

1. Error   5   Invalid expression term ')'
2. Error   2   Expected ; or = (cannot specify constructor arguments in
   declaration)
3. Error   9   Expected ; or = (cannot specify constructor arguments in
   declaration)
4. Error   1   ; expected

Comment: where is the `If exists...` part

Comment: IF EXISTS code i have deleted from the code.

Comment: Add that part. You cannot say its not working you have to explain why its not working

Answer (score 0):

Thats not the right syntax. Try this.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
           FROM   UserInfo
           WHERE  User_Name = @Name
                  AND Email = @Email
                  AND EPF_Number = @EPFNumber
                  AND Department = @DPT
                  AND Laptop_Model = @Model
                  AND Laptop_Serial = @Serial
                  AND Issu_Date = @Date
                  AND Hostname = @Host
                  AND Image = @Photo)
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO UserInfo
                  (User_Name,
                   Email,
                   EPF_Number,
                   Department,
                   Laptop_Model,
                   Laptop_Serial,
                   Issu_Date,
                   Hostname,
                   Image)
      VALUES      ( @Name,
                    @Email,
                    @EPFNumber,
                    @DPT,
                    @Model,
                    @Serial,
                    @Date,
                    @Host,
                    @Photo)
  END
```